# Cannot get Correct month for a call from call log history

Tags: android

I am trying to extract information from the call log of the
android. I am getting the call date that is one month back from the
actual time of call. I mean to say that the information extracted by
my code for the date of call is one mont back than the actual call
date.

I have the following in the Emulator:

I saved a contact. Then I made a call to the contact.

Code:

I have 3 ways of extracting call Date information but getting the same
wrong result.  My code is as follows:

```
/*  Make the query to call log content */
Cursor callLogResult = context.getContentResolver().query(
    CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, null,  null, null);

int columnIndex =  callLogResult.getColumnIndex(Calls.DATE);
Long timeInResult = callLogResult.getLong(columnIndex);

/* Method 1 to change the milliseconds obtained to the readable date formate */
            Time time = new Time();
            time.toMillis(true);
            time.set(timeInResult);

String callDate= time.monthDay+"-"+time.month+"-"+time.year;


/*  Method 2 for extracting the date from tha value read from the column */

           Calendar calendar =  Calendar.getInstance();
           calendar.setTimeInMillis(time);
           String  Month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) ;

/* Method 3 for extracting date from the result obtained  */

          Date date = new Date(timeInResult);
          String mont = date.getMonth()
```

While using the Calendar method , I also tried to set the DayLight
SAving Offset but it didnot worked,

```
      calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Paris"));
      int DST_OFFSET = calendar.get(  Calendar.DST_OFFSET );   // DST_OFFSET

      Boolean isSet = calendar.getTimeZone().useDaylightTime();

      if(isSet)
      calendar.set(Calendar.DST_OFFSET , 0);

      int reCheck = calendar.get(Calendar.DST_OFFSET );
```

But the value is not set to 0 in recheck.  I am getting the wrong
month value by using this also.

Please some one  help me where I am wrong?  or is this the error in
emulator ??

Thanks,
Nishant Kumar
Engineering Student

Answer (score 1):

Calandar's months are from 0 to 11
You need to add 1 to the month Caladar is giving you.
I know, this is strange.

Answer (score 0):

Try `new Date(timeInResult);`